# Prevent var value (selected option) changes on window scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, onchange, addeventlistener

Get the selected option value and pass it to a function. However, notice on window scroll the value changes and return all previously selected value.

See code at [codepen](https://codepen.io/shirojay/pen/voVZQK)
Check the console.

**To reproduce issue**

1. On the dropdown, select 2018 and scroll. In console, as expected behaviour returns

```
"change: 2018"
"init: 2018"
"scroll: 2018"
```

2. Clear console. Change to 2019 and scroll. In console, returns a loop of "2018" "2019". Expected behaviour "2019" only.

```
"change: 2019"
"init: 2019"
"scroll: 2018"
"scroll: 2019"
"scroll: 2018"
"scroll: 2019"
```

```
(function () {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var select = document.querySelector('select')

    // Register click event listener for select element
    select.addEventListener('change', handleLibsynSelectChange, true)

    // Handle select change
    function handleLibsynSelectChange(e) {
      var year = e.target.value
      console.log('change: ' + year)
      handleLibsynInit(year)
    }

    function handleLibsynInit(libsynFilterYear) {
      console.log('init: ' + libsynFilterYear)
      window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        console.log('scroll: ' + libsynFilterYear)
        // other functions to execute on window scroll which need the var libsynFilterYear
      })
    }
  })
})()
```

Comment: Not a bug, you aren't clearing previous `scroll` listeners. You really ought to have 1 listener.

Comment: These are the sorts of problems you run into when you use one event handler to create event listeners on other elements. It is a bad practice in general. Each change of the `<select>` adds a new scroll listener

Comment: How do I pass the selected value from the change handler to the scroll handler?

Comment: You don't really need to. You can  use `select.value` in the scroll handler

Comment: True that! I could actually use select[select.selectedIndex].value inside the scroll listener. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About over this comment:

**How do I pass the selected value from the change handler to the scroll handler?**

*Just grab the selected value in your 'change' event listener.*

```
(function () {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var select = document.querySelector('select');
    var yearSelected = -1;
    // Register click event listener for select element
    select.addEventListener('change', handleLibsynSelectChange, true);
    // Handle select change
    function handleLibsynSelectChange(e) {
      yearSelected = e.target.value
    };
    var listener = function () {
      console.dir('scroll : ' + yearSelected);
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll',listener);
  });
})()
```

Comment: Thanks. Works. Could you kindly explain why var yearSelected = -1 ?

Comment: Hi Shiro, just mean initialize an unselected year, so you don't need to compare about undefined / null this value, just compare the value